# Performance: if else vs switch, while vs for, for each vs for, print vs printf

Tags: php, performance, loops, conditional-statements

I was testing all these different constructs using `getrusage()` to calculate the variations of `(ru_utime + ru_stime)` before and after executing them.
It turns out there's no little difference in performing the same task for similar constructs. Here are the results:
`printf` (1.5 ± 0.5)% faster than `print`
`foreach` (6.0 ± 1.0)% faster than a `for` loop(iterating over an indexed array of 1kk elements)
`for` (9.0 ± 1.0)% faster than a `while` loop
`if/else` (8.0 ± 1.0)% faster than a `switch`(tested over two cases, 6 cases, and 10 possible cases).

So I was wondering, do these differences really matter? If we use all the most efficient such constructs in our code, will it make some difference? Maybe 6%, 8% there, 9% or 10% there, summed up will change the efficiency of our code?
Or will these differences nonetheless be not noticeable, I mean the response of the server to requests will almost not vary? Also, if we use `if/else` over `switch`, `for` over `while`, `printf` over `print`, `foreach` over `for`, will it eat up more RAM?

Comment: Yes, please use a profiler for the big picture. Then look at the SQL queries instead.

Comment: [PHP freshmen wants to optimize...](http://www.quickmeme.com/img/d2/d26f0ee993134aaee20c8e67eff93aa6d089cd82f912a68316a38de4a3b7c551.jpg)

Comment: You use the __appropriate__ constructs for __readability__, not necessarily the fastest when the differences are measured in nanoseconds

Comment: And often performance will vary depending on what you need to do inside your loops: e.g. if you need access to the associative key for an array, then there's little sense in using `for()`

Comment: mark they are in percentages not nanoseconds. But the core of my question isn't this, but do these loops and conditions really affect the server's response time, or they play little role in this?

Comment: And with the most recent versions of PHP, you also have an opcode optimizer that will change the underlying code structures to a degree anyway

Comment: If you want something to run fast, the first thing you should optimise away is PHP itself.

Comment: @Erik So I guess that database queries or file access of remote calls are never a performance overhead in other languages?

Comment: @MarkBaker: compared to *the specific loop or test/eval construct* used (inside of which lives the slow operation)?

Answer (score 2):

Answering your question using `StackOverflow` answers, in terms of performance:

For `if/else` vs `switch`: Same performance ([more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773047/which-is-faster-and-better-switch-case-or-if-else-if)).

For `for` vs `foreach` vs `while`: It doesn't matter ([more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12847502/for-loop-vs-while-loop-vs-foreach-loop-php)).

For `printf` vs `print`: One not better than the other ([more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504797/php-echo-print-printf)).

My humble opinion is that you use whatever seems more comfortable to you and/or covers your needs better (there are slight differences between each other, in other terms than performance, and this depends on what you need). In terms of performance, there are other things that you should take care of in order to maximize performance, such as decreasing the `O` complexity of code used in your program, network delays handling, parallelization of tasks when needed etc. Your question is a little bit general, so I tried to answer the same way.

Comment: Your using answers mostly based on intuitions, while I tested them myself. Anyhow, my question isn't about which is more performant, but is about performance in terms of these operations. Do these operation really affect the server response, or they do little differences

Comment: Is your system perfect in other sections, such as algorithms complexity etc? I think that the differences are very small, unless you are using a system that desperately needs optimization in that level.....

Answer (score 0):

1. You are right. Few percent doesn't really matter.
2. The scalability of the operations can much more dramatically influence your application's performance than these few percent. Scalability means in this sense how your system will behave if you receive 2x, 10x more amount of data. Will your system be slowed down only 2x, 10x (if it is linear), or 4x, 100x (quadratic) etc. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability
3. This problem usually occurs on database side as other mentioned. There are the "big" operations. There are the data which can be big.
4. Most of the developers don't have to care too much about resources. And yes. profiling is the proper way to handle performance issues.

Comment: But suppose a loop is executed 10 million times, and Suppose if it is a for loop it takes 8 secs, but if a while it takes 9 secs in total. Then suppose further at the same time a condition is executed 10 million times, and an if else takes 10 secs, while a switch takes 11 secs. And further a foreach which takes also 8 secs, while a for 8.5 secs. So it turns out that after 10 million runs, there is a 2.5 seconds difference. Is this not big? You may say 10 millions is a big number, but do we not in programming scale these operation in terms of big numbers? Millions, billions etc.

Comment: Whatever is inside that loop will count for MUCH more than the looping construct itself. And if you're running 10 million calculations in a loop, you'd probably be better off running those calculations in a different language altogether.

Comment: Practically if you see the number 10 million, it can mean 2 things. 1. This amount of data is coming from somewhere. And accessing this somewhere will be the bottleneck (IO vs CPU). 2. Something is already scaled wrongly, and it is much more efficient to try to fix the scaling issue, which can convert the 10 million, to 10 thousand, than wasting time for the few percent.

Comment: I'm not saying 10 millions for a singe execution, suppose thousands of times there have been requests and in total this number of iterations was executed in say 1 hour

Comment: I am sure that we can find/create scenarios where the few percent matters, but in the reality this is very rare. At least based on my experience.

Answer (score 0):

OP writes:

> *Do these differences really matter? If we use all the most efficient such constructs in our code, will it make some difference?*

Well, yes and no.  Are you programming ultra-low latency applications?  Hard (deterministic) real-time applications?  If yes, then yes.  Waiting on keyboard input from a user? It's a miracle your CPU doesn't die from boredom.  So, no.

A 9% difference may be negligible (your Elf-Lord doesn't kill the troll), or it might extremely significant (your grandmother's life-support system kills her).

Basically, this is not a question that can be answered here.  Setting aside environment/execution/compiler optimization issues: it's not only a book-length subject, but the specific book would depend on what kind of programs are you talking about, and what the consequences and requirements are for the performance envelope.  I would guess that for 99.99% of programmers, the difference between a `switch` or `if/else` statement, or similar peephole optimization, is (in real terms) absolutely zero.

The old maxim "make it readable, make it run, then make it run fast if you have to" is probably your best course of action.  Even in that extremely rare case where it might matter, just be sure to use a profiler to determine where the "where" part of the "make it run fast" phase is really needed.

Comment: If want the code of my "grandmother's life-support system" to be readable and maintainable thank you very much. Unless you made a typo and you meant "mother in law's"

Comment: As do I, @PeeHaa.  Hence trotting out the old "make it readable" saw. I have had to write code where software failures would have real-world consequences (beyond money), and in those cases the focus was *always* on correctness, testability, and readability - and those things usually go hand-in-hand (-in-hand? how many hands?).

Comment: @PeeHaa: *snerk* Just read the edit to your comment. You owe me Windex for my monitor.  Also, I was sorry to hear that you would not be designing the network or coming up with an IP address allocation solution for "SeeM3FictionalNetwork" or whatever it was. I would have probably PeeHaa'd on myself to read it.