# Another PHP require_once issue

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [require_once () or die() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163473/require-once-or-die-not-working)

I try to include a file with require_once and i get:

> Warning: require_once(1) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/phpscrape/index.php on line 3
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '1' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/phpscrape/index.php on line 3
>   I can do a cat /var/www/phpscrape/simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php which means the path is correct.

The permissions are www-data:www-data same as index.php which is executing. To be sure i also set chmod 777 but that didnt help either.

The command line is:

```
<? php
require_once("/var/www/phpscrape/simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php") or die("no such file");
```

Comment: This is probably a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

You are hitting a weird side effect of the fact that `require` is not a real function, but a language construct.

`require` does not require its parameter to be wrapped into parentheses.

Therefore, what `require` interprets as the parameter is *the full rest of the line*:

```
(("/var/www/phpscrape/simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php") or die("no such file"))
```

which equals `1`.

I would either just drop the `die()` (require will die on error anyway) or do a `file_exists()` check beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

```
  require_once("var/www/phpscrape/simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php") or die("no such file");
```

Without the / at the beginning

If not working try:

```
 require_once("phpscrape/simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php") or die("no such file");
```

Comment: Nope, the reason is more tricky. See my answer