# Is it possible to disjunct two require_once statements with OR operator to use the latter as fallback?

Tags: php

Is there a way to perform double `require_once` statement where the second one as a fallback if the first one fails?

For example: I can do this

```
mysql_query() or die("Boo");
```

Could I do:

```
require_once('filename') or require_once('../filename');
```

If one fails it reverts to the other?

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate. Wait a second …

Comment: @Gumbo possible duplicate of [require_once () or die() not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163473/require-once-or-die-not-working)

Comment: linked in certian ways. but surely not a duplicate. he is talking about suppressing the message, im talking about redirection

Comment: @Shahmir Javaid: Yes, you’re right. Sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do this because of a weird little quirk in PHP. `require_once()` is a language construct, not a function. It will interpret *the whole line* as the argument:

```
(('filename') or require_once('../filename'))
```

(added braces for clarity) the result of this operation is `1`.

Use `is_readable()` instead.

```
if (is_readable($filename)) 
  require_once($filename); 
    else require_once("../$filename");
```

or a shorter version that should work:

```
require_once(is_readable($filename) ? $filename : "../$filename");
```

Comment: I will Acecpt your answer, asks me to wait 9 minutes :D. Another way i did get around this is `require_once('/var/www/html/filename')` by giving the look up to start from root it dosent matter where the file is. This is for linux only. :D

Answer (score 2):

@Pekka is correct.  I'd add something else though, that might get rid of the issue entirely.  If you have files in several different places, you can edit the include paths so that require() and include() look in a variety of places.  See [set_include_path()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php)

The example in the manual adds a new path to the existing include path:

```
$path = '/usr/lib/pear';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
```