# php in html not working

Tags: php, html

Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE=HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
require("connect.php") or die("failed to connect to server.");

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
echo'Goodwork!';
}else{

echo'<form action="signup.php" method="POST">
Fistname: <input type="text" name="fname"/></br>
Lastname: <input type="text" name="lname"/></br>
Phone Number: <input type="text" name="phonenumber"/></br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email1"/></br>
Confirm Email: <input type="text" name="email2"/></br>
Password: <input type="password" name="pass1"/></br>
Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="pass2"/></br>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>';


}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

However when I run this the browser just gives me a white page with no form. I have tried taking away the "if (isset($_POST['submit'])){echo'Goodwork!';}" bit but have had no luck. What is up with my PHP?

Comment: Check the file extension is .php. If it is, try creating a blank php file with `phpinfo();` in it, and loading it on your web server, to check that PHP is correctly installed.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Are you using XAMPP or WAMP for your php environmnet.  If using XAMPP, please make sure that you saved the file in the xampp/htdocs folder and if using WAMP ensure that you saved it in the WWW folder.

Comment: Put error reporting on - `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: See [this duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163473/require-once-or-die-not-working). `or` is not necessary for `require` and is giving you a fatal error, ie the white screen of death.

Comment: do you have created connect.php? if yes then check for the path. you have included it as require. if it does not reach to the file, it will stop the execution.

Answer (score 0):

Check your connect.php and put `die("failed to connect to server.");` statement in connect.php file and execute it when your mysql_connect(); failed to connect with database.